# Styled component custom font unrecognized with react native elements

Tags: react-native, expo, styled-components, react-native-elements

I'm trying to wrap the react-native-elements Input component with styled-components and to use custom font.

When I'm using the above code everything works fine and the font shown correctly:

```html
<Input
    placeholder={placeholder}
    placeholderTextColor="white"
    style={{ fontFamily: "Arimo-Italic" }}
    autoCapitalize="none"
/>
```

This code works too (without react-native-elements components)

```js
export const StyledText = styled.Text`
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: Arimo;
`;
```

But, when I'm trying to wrap the react-native-elements Input component with styled-components I'm getting this error ***Unrecognized font family 'Arimo'***

here is my styled component code:

```js
import { Input } from "react-native-elements";
import styled from "styled-components";
    
export const StyledInput = styled(Input).attrs({
    textAlign: "right",
    fontFamily: "Arimo",
    marginTop: 50,
    inputContainerStyle: {
        borderBottomColor: "#2f2f2f",
        borderBottomWidth: "0.33px",
    },
});
```

And here is my app component with loading font function:

```js
function App() {
    let [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
        Arimo: require("./assets/fonts/Arimo-Regular.ttf"),
        "Arimo-Italic": require("./assets/fonts/Arimo-Italic.ttf"),
    });
    
    if (!fontsLoaded) {
        return <AppLoading />;
    } else {
        return (
          <NavigationContainer theme={MyTheme}>
            <Stack.Navigator>
              <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
            </Stack.Navigator>
          </NavigationContainer>
        );
    }
}
    
export default App;
```

I'm running the code on my iOS device

Comment: have you tried this https://forums.expo.io/t/sdk-37-unrecognized-font-family/35201/18
or this https://reactnativeelements.com/docs/troubleshooting/#-fontfamily-font-name-is-not-a-system-font

Comment: which version of react-navigation you are using?

Comment: Why are you using `attrs `?

Comment: @diedu I didn't, I will try but I think it's more related to styled-components as it works in any other way I use the font without styled component.

Comment: @MRPMOHIBURRAHMAN 5.9.4

Comment: @WaheedAkhtar It how you style react-native-elements using styled-components https://github.com/react-native-elements/react-native-elements/issues/1786

Comment: better to have some reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

**This works for apps created with expo and considering you already imported the fonts in somewhere of your app using expo-font.**

Personally I don't like this approach, and I think this issue is from styled-components, so in order to use custom fonts, this approach will work. You can create a proxy component, example:

```js
    // ./Styled.js (our styled component without a font-family property)
    import styled from 'styled-components/native';
    
    export const StyledTitle1 = styled.Text`
      font-size: 18px;
    `;

    // ./Title1.jsx (our proxy component)
    import React from 'react';
    import { StyledTitle1 } from '../Styled';

    function Title1 ({ children, ...rest }) {
      const customStyles = rest.style ?? {};
      return (
        <StyledTitle1 {...rest} style={{ fontFamily: 'Roboto-Bold', ...customStyles }}>
          {children}
        </StyledTitle1>
      )
    }
    
    export default Title1;
```

So, the fontFamily will be used only in the proxy component, all others styles can be concentered to the styled component.